# Why is the @@ERROR always 0 and @@ROWCOUNT always 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I create a table like:

[image]

then I execute this statement:

```
update test 
set tname = 'Joker' 
where tid % 2 = 0
```

it shows:

[image]

which means 'there are two rows affected' in Chinese.

But if execute `print @@rowcount` immediately, the result is:

[image]

What else, if execute `insert into test values('Paul','foo')`, the result is:

[image]

which means:

> Message 8101, Level 16, Status 1, Line 21.
>   Only when column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON, you can set values in the identity column of 'test' table explicitly'.

But if then execute `print @@ERROR`, it shows:

[image]

which I think should be 8101.

Could someone tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Always post sample data as text in table format instead of posting it as image. It will be helpful for demo/testing purposes

Comment: Reason why images are discouraged is listed here:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

First issue is not replicable, I have prepared demo script

```
create table test(tid int identity(1,1), tname varchar(100))
insert into test values ('James'),('Jake'),('Tom'),('Mary')

update test 
set tname = 'Joker' 
where tid % 2 = 0

select @@ROWCOUNT --returns 2
```

Second issue is because you are running the `select @error` statement separately. That's why you are getting `0`. If you run the last two statements together you will get `545` as result

```
set  identity_insert test on
insert into test values ('James'),('Jake'),('Tom'),('Mary')
select @@ERROR --returns 545
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second question (it would have been a good idea to post these as 2 separate questions), your SQL statement is trying to insert 'Paul' into the `tid` column.  You need to separate the values like this:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Paul'), ('foo')
```

Better yet, be explicit with the column names:

```
INSERT INTO test (tname) VALUES ('Paul'), ('foo')
```

Comment: The OP is not asking about why he is getting an error but why @@error is not showing the correct number

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Well, hopefully his next question was going to be how to fix the query...